# In JMockit, how to specify times for a series of calls?

Tags: jmockit

I have something like:

```
new Expectations() {{
    mock0.f();
    mock1.f();

    mock0.f();
    mock1.f();

    mock0.f();
    mock1.f();
}};
```

Is there a way I can use the 'times =' specification?  Something like:

```
new Expectations() {{
    {
        mock0.f();
        mock1.f();
    }
    times = 3;
}};
```

I /could/ have a loop in my Expectations, but I really hate cyclomatic complexities greater than one in my unit tests.

Note that I want to keep using strict expectations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Expectations` constructor which takes a `numberOfIterations` argument:

```
new Expectations(3) {{
    {
        mock0.f();
        mock1.f();
    }
}};
```

`NonStrictExpectations` and `Verifications` also support it.